# Randomly Create Enemies In Android Studio

Tags: android, random

I'm making my first android game, and i want to create a random enemy every three seconds, i have six enemies but my code it's not working!!

I don't know what i'm missing or doing wrong, i have a red line under `(rand == 0)` and `(rand == 1)`.

Please help!

The code i'm using:

```
if (EnemyElapsed > (2000-alien.getScore()/4)){
    switch ((int) (rand.nextDouble() * (2))) {
        if(rand == 0){
            enemy.add(new Enemy(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dog), WIDTH + 10,60, 250, 250, alien.getScore(), 2));
            enemyStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        else if(rand == 1){
            enemy.add(new Enemy(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aalien), WIDTH + 10,60, 250, 250, alien.getScore(), 2));
            enemyStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hover over the red line, see error message, fix error.

Comment: You need to look up how switch works.

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem**:

`rand` is a [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) object, you can't compare it with an `int`.

This is why you have the red line under `(rand == 0)` and `(rand == 1)` .

---

**The solution**:

You must use **case** instead of **if/else** blocks

```
if (EnemyElapsed > (2000-alien.getScore()/4)){
        switch ((int) (rand.nextDouble() * (2))) {

            case 0:
               enemy.add(new Enemy(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dog), WIDTH + 10,60, 250, 250, alien.getScore(), 2));
               enemyStartTime = System.nanoTime();
            break;

            case 1:
               enemy.add(new Enemy(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aalien), WIDTH + 10,60, 250, 250, alien.getScore(), 2));
               enemyStartTime = System.nanoTime();
            break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked Thanks, no red lines but would it display randomly??